# How can I web scrape the details hidden behind popup?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the webpage:
https://esge2023.process.y-congress.com/ScientificProcess/schedule/

I have to click on each row on the page and scrape the details behind that. The URL changes into a format like https://esge2023.process.y-congress.com/ScientificProcess/schedule/?sessionGuid=e7f90422-1d57-49be-bd32-eb0bc9e6c35b

The difference between the base page and the new page is the ?/sessionGuid part.

The problem is, using beautiful soup I cannot identify where this element is or the associated href/anchor tag. By this, I mean I can't find any hrefs that end with ?/sessionGuid. It looks like this only appears after you click on a session.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://esge2023.process.y-congress.com/ScientificProcess/schedule/'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,
                            'html.parser')

soup.find_all('a')
```

Can anyone recommend ideas? Is selenium the way forward?